# Is to possible to set up automatic execution and download of Databricks scripts?

Tags: automation, databricks, azure-data-lake

I have developed a few tables in Databrick which pull data from our Google query and Azure data lake data. Those are used in Excel dashboards and SQL tables. But it depends on me manually running and downloading the tables daily or weekly.

How can I set up jobs so the scripts can be run and tables downloaded to my drive automatically?

Then I could use PowerShell to move and rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Databricks Notebook activity` in Azure Data Factory (ADF) to run the Databricks Notebooks and schedule the execution based on event or any particular time and interval.

To create a ADF pipeline to run Notebook, you need to perform following tasks:

You perform the following steps in this tutorial:

- Create a data factory.
- Create **Linked Service** to make connection to the Databricks Notebook.
- Create a pipeline that uses **Databricks Notebook Activity**.
- Trigger a pipeline run.
- Monitor the pipeline run.

Refer the official Microsoft tutorial [Run a Databricks notebook with the Databricks Notebook Activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) to follow the step-by-step points for deployment.

Once done, you can trigger your pipeline immediately to check how it is working. To automate the pipeline execution, you can create `Schedule Trigger`. By doing so you can make the pipeline to execute at any particular time and after certain interval of time. Refer [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory).